# "Save image as" in Chrome and Firefox not working as before

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

Until now when I would right-click on an image in the Chrome or FF browsers a window would pop up that allowed me to type a name for the image to be saved WITHOUT having to click into the window to make it active. In other words, I could simply right-click, select "save image as," then type the name I want and press Enter to save -- done! But now when I go to save an image I have to click into the name field in order to type a name. Why? I cannot figure out what has changed since I haven't made any changes manually to either browser that would affect this otherwise normal procedure.

Edit I:
Chrome: Version 112.0.5615.165 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Firefox: 112.0.2 (64-bit)(Snap)
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
OS Type: 64-bit
GNOME: 42.5
Windowing Sys: Wayland

Comment: Version of Ubuntu? Snap or deb versions of the browsers?